# Difficulty in switching between various versions of code and commiting changes using SVN in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, svn, version-control

I am using SVN for version control in MATLAB 2014b. I have edited my file '*main.m*' three times and commited changes to SVN repository. Thus there are three versions of my file, say commmit1, commmit2 and commmit3.  Now, I wanted to revert my file from commit3 to commit2, make some changes in commit2 and finally commit this edited version to create commit4. I have successfully reverted from commit3 to commit2 and made some changes in it. But, now I am unable to commit changes made to commit2. It shows error ***commit failed,'main.m' is out of date***. Please help me in sorting out the issue.

Comment: which software you are using as SVN client?

Comment: I am using inbuilt SVN provided by MATLAB 2014b

Comment: What specific command did you use to "revert" to commit2? I guess you did an "update to revision" when what you needed to do was a "reverse merge" operation.

Comment: I am not using any commands for version control. I am doing it using GUI provided by MATLAB (right clicking the files and selecting the options i want to do like commit / revert / tag etc)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TortoiseSVN as client the follow this procedure.

- Select the file and right click and then click on TortoiseSVN
- Proess the show log option from drop down menu andyou will see a window
- select the specific checkin which you want to revert to.
- Press right click and then press "Revert to this revision"

Comment: I have reverted my code from current to previous version and made some changes in previous version. Now, I want to commit the changes made to previous version.  But, I am unable to commit changes.